# Detecting scheduled threads on linux

Tags: linux, pthreads

I need to detect whether a given thread is currently scheduled to a CPU or not. I am on a linux system with pthreads. Say that my code is running on a signal handler and I know that there are threads X and Y in my app, and from within my signal handler I want to check if X and Y are currently scheduled or not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you trying to do? checking that a thread is 'running' or even 'runnable' gives you information that gets stale _really_ fast.

Comment: What I am trying to do is explained in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if you have to ask this question, you are probably thinking incorrectly.  Whatever answer you are going to get is going to be immediately outdated and whatever you plan to do about the answer is going to be subject to massive race conditions.

However, in theory you can look at /proc/getpid()/task/threadid/status and find out if a particular thread is running or not.  Note this is very much a linux thing and any mapping between "threadid" and pthread_self()'s return code or pthread_create's pthread_t copy-out is very much not a standard.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just came back to report that /proc has what I want, you beat me to it. However, I don't appreciate your 'thinking incorrectly' comment. I am working on a system that not only is linux-only, but also it is only supposed to work on a particular distro. I don't care about the race conditions either (it is a statistical thing that I want to do)

Comment: @bugur: You should take a look at the `perf sched` tool - it's a good way to analyse thread scheduling behaviour.

Comment: @caf: thanks, that is interesting. I have a more special use case. I am tracking a number of threads and trying to figure out how much time they spend in each 'stage' of their processing. Each thread tracks its current stage. Transfers between stages may happen very quickly, or very slowly due to blocking code paths.  Right now, I have way of profiling how much time each tread spends in each stage. The problem is, I can't differentiate between blocking versus actual work.

Comment: @bugur: Wouldn't the amount of CPU time each thread accumulates be a more useful source of this information?  (Unless the work it does is somehow bursty).